# Laravel 5.3 does not have webpack.mix.js by default in the root location

Tags: laravel, webpack, gulp

When I install Laravel 5.3 with the following composer command in windows command prompt, I get the Laravel installation in the folder `laravel_53_again`.

`composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel_53_again 5.3.*`

But at the root location, I see `gulpfile.js`. No `webpack.mix.js` is found there. I want to use webpack and not gulp as the module bundler.

I however remember  that I would get webpack instead of gulp in the root location through composer installation before.

How can I get `webpack.mix.js` file instead of `gulp.js` by default in the root  location on installing Laravel through composer command in command prompt in windows 10 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get webpack.mix.js at the root of a fresh copy of laravel, you need to install [5.4](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/5.4) (or up) instead of [5.3](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/5.3).  Follow those links to see for yourself on github.

Comment: Previously `webpack.mix.js` was available in the root location for version 5.3. So that has been changed later for 5.3 ?

Comment: When did you see this?  The gulp.js file hasn't been touched in 3 years in that repo.

Comment: Oh, I made a serious mistake when I told that in my previous comment ....

Comment: Just found this article too, https://mattstauffer.com/blog/introducing-laravel-mix-new-in-laravel-5-4/ seems a simple mix up regardless, I'm curious,  why 5.3 if you're doing a fresh install? Some extension that doesn't support a newer version?

Comment: I am going through this book ' Full-Stack Vue.js 2 and Laravel 5' ( https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/full-stack-vuejs-2-and-laravel-5) which uses Laravel 5 and most probably 5.3. In 5.8 for example I do not see  under `resources` the `assets` folder which has been used in the example.